# PFFacebookUtils can't logout from Facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, parse-platform, pffacebookutils

I know that this question has already been asked here, but nothing works for me. I can't logout from Facebook. No matter what I do I still see "You have already authorized AppName" screen.

I tried:

```
[[PFFacebookUtils facebookLoginManager] logOut];
```

which nullifies the current access token but no luck.

I tried deleting permissions but it does not work as well. Once permissions are deleted then it just asks user for permissions but it asks the same user.

I tried just:

```
[PFUser logout];
```

but still nothing.

Any ideas, guys?

Comment: When you user [PFUser logout], what happens?

Comment: PFUser gets logged out, that's it.

Comment: Your question asks why you can't logout from Facebook in your app...what do you want to happen after the user is logged out?

Comment: I want to be able to login with a different Facebook user. But I can't. I see a screen (it is SFSafariViewController as I understand) which says "You have already authorised AppName". But I want to see the login form so a new user could login

Comment: On the safari window, you will have to log out that Facebook user and login as a new Facebook user.

Comment: there's no logout option on that screen

Comment: My mistake, you are right. I looks like you have to go to Facebook.com in the Safari app and login as a new user there. Let me know if this works and I will post it as an answer.

Comment: it does not work. I've logged into the app with a Facebook user, but I'm logged out in Safari app

Comment: I can be signed in with user A through SFSafariViewController into my app and be signed in with user B in the Safari app. They do not touch each other at all

Comment: For my app, I use PFFacebookUtils also. I just tried it on my device. I logged out from my Facebook account in the Safari app and went back into my app. I went to log in with Facebook and it asks me to log in first. Make sure you are logged out in the safari app.

Comment: yes, you're right. it works. yet, isn't there a way to do that programmatically? I can't believe it. It is so important and it's missing. And there's logOut method on FBSDKLoginmanager which doesn't work. so weird...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, buddy. please post your solution as an aswer so I could at least upvote it. You deserve some more reputation.

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean...maybe in the future! Please mark the answer that I posted

Comment: I've upvoted your answer, but I don't want to mark it as accepted by now. There's a little hope for magician who will tell me how to do that programmatically. I'll accept your answer tomorrow if no such magician emerges by that time

Comment: Sounds good...thanks!

Comment: The same applies to your answer to my question about sign up/log in. If nobody gives better answer tomorrow I'll accept it

Comment: is there any chance you can help with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36224389/pffacebookutils-login-methods-do-nothing-if-facebook-app-is-installed ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user will have to go into the Safari app and log out there.